# How to solve $xy(1+xy^2)y'=1$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE
$$xy(1+xy^2)y'=1$$

How to go about it?

I tried substituting $1 +xy^2$ as $v$ and going forward but couldn't get an answer.

Comment: you can refer to [this link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%3D1%2F%28x*y*%281%2Bx*y%5E2%29%29)

Comment: Edit your question to show what happened when you used that substitution.

Answer (score 1):

This is the classical Bernoulli equation when $x$ is a function and $y$ is a variable
So $$\frac{dx}{dy} - xy=x^2y^3$$ $\Rightarrow$ multiply the equation by $\frac{1}{x^2}$. Let's replace the variable $z=\frac{1}{x}$ $$\Rightarrow
\frac{dz}{dy}=\frac{-1}{x^2}\cdot\frac{dx}{dy}$$ $\Rightarrow$ the classical Lagrange equation :)

Comment: +1 for a nice solution.   But use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and Welcome to math SE :)

Comment: Ok) Check my answer pls x(e^y(-y^3+3y^2-6y)+6y+C)=e^y